# How to ssh and use a personal bashrc without getting disconnected

Tags: ssh, bash

I would like to be able to `ssh` to a remote host and run some repetitive commands on it before continuing my work.

I have been trying the following command with no luck:

```
ssh uname@remotehost.com 'source /path/to/my/bashrc; ls /logs'
```

The commands run fine, however I am not being presented with a shell to continue my work.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing one thing. That if you provide `ssh` command to run, the session will end as soon as the session ends. This mean as soon as your `ls` command ends, also `ssh` will return. To achieve your requested behaviour you need to add the `bash`/`shell` to the end and request `tty` allocation, like this:

```
ssh -tt uname@remotehost.com 'source /path/to/my/bashrc; ls /logs; bash'
```

or you can substitute the `bash` command with other shell you prefer.

Answer (score 2):

You don't get a shell because when you pass a command to SSH to run remotely, that *replaces* the shell invocation.

If you want things to happen when you login, you should add those to the account's `.bashrc`.  If the account is shared, well, (1) stop doing that, and (2) there are various ways that the shell can determine who exactly is logging in and do things conditionally.

Answer (score 0):

When I have many commands to run on a remote host, I like to use Here Documents[1]

```
ssh $SERVER << EOF
command 1
command 2
command 3
EOF
```

[1]http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html